# Batch Script Timestamp Variable without spaces YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS

Tags: batch-file, cmd, timestamp, filenames, datetime-format

I've created a timestamp variable in a batch script like so...

```
set TIMESTAMP=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%
```

There is an issue though when the HH is only a single digit I get...

```
YYYY-MM-DD- 2-MM-SS
```

instead of

```
YYYY-MM-DD-02-MM-SS
```

How do I consistently generate the timestamp without spaces?

Comment: Closely related: [How do I get current datetime on the Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "timestamp=%timestamp: =0%"
```

replaces spaces with zeroes.

See `set /?` from the prompt for documentation.

Comment: I can agree that this works if the current locale setting is just right. However, it still leaves the result as a locale specific format. @LotPings answer is locale independent. It works everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use locale/user settings dependent date time variables but wmic:

```
@Echo off
For /f "delims=." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^20'
) Do Set DT=%%A
Set "TIMESTAMP=%DT:~0,4%-%DT:~4,2%-%DT:~6,2%-%DT:~8,2%-%DT:~10,2%-%DT:~12,2%"
Set TimeStamp
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_45465890.cmd
TIMESTAMP=2017-08-02-18-42-07
```

Or use PowerShell and let it do the formatting:

```
@Echo off
For /f %%A in ('powershell -NoP -C "get-date -f \"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss\""') Do Set TimeStamp=%%A
Set TimeStamp
```

Comment: The PowerShell variant... GREAT ANSWER! I would have needed it more than 10+ years ago! THANKS!